# Is there an equivalent of Julia's metaprogramming and macros for JavaScript and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, macros, julia, metaprogramming

I'm used to Julia macros (metaprogramming), that are a quite handy way of generating flexible code.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/

Is there an equivalent for JavaScript or TypeScript. Such as a package or a way of working?

Comment: kind of. But thre's a reason that [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is usually referred to as *evil*. It may be "handy" untill you realize that by doing so, you may have created an API where potentially every 3rd party code (like any ad on your page) may get access to the *private state* of your app and execute commands *in your name* on your customers computers. Not sure if you'd consider that a good tradeoff.

Comment: You're probably better off with a language that has a real macro system and compiles to JavaScript. E.g., ClojureScript, or Nim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent. Neither ECMAScript nor TypeScript have macros.

There is a proposal for [*Decorators*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), which would allow you to do a tiny subset of what you can do with macros, but that proposal is still in [Stage 2](https://tc39.es/process-document/) of the specification process.

There are currently no official proposals to add Macros to ECMAScript (I went through the list of all Stage 3, Stage 2, Stage 1, and Stage 0 proposals) nor have there ever been (I also checked inactive and withdrawn proposals). There *is* however recurring discussion about it, not the least since at one point, some Scheme designers were also part of the ECMAScript committee.

What would be achieved using macros in languages like Julia, Scheme, Rust, Boo, Nemerle, and co. is usually solved with *source-to-source compilers* (sometimes called *transpilers*) in the ECMAScript community. The most popular of which is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Babel is *mostly* used to "compile away" newer language features, i.e. allow a programmer to use the latest language features and even not-yet-released proposals, but still run the code in environments where only an older version of the language is available.

There *are*, however, some third-party macro libraries available that add macros to ECMAScript via … you guessed it … source-to-source transpilation. One of these is [Sweet.js](https://sweetjs.org).